# How to add a new button in woocommerce single product page and lead to order details page where current product has been purchased?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm planning to create a website that sells virtual products, each product only needs to be purchased once before downloading and can be downloaded forever, so I want to hide the (A product) add to cart button when the user has already purchased (A product), and at the same time Add a new button after hiding (A product) Add to cart button, I hope this button can directly lead to view the user's purchase (A product) order page (for example: the new button named (Download) will jump to User purchase order details page, for example, the order number is 624, so the directed URL should be /my-account/view-order/624/)

Is this possible? How should I modify these codes?

I plan to create a website that sells virtual products, each product only needs to be purchased once before downloading, so I use the following code to hide the add to cart button when the user has already purchased (A product)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'bbloomer_deny_purchase_if_already_purchased', 9999, 2 );
  
function bbloomer_deny_purchase_if_already_purchased( $is_purchasable, $product ) {
   if ( is_user_logged_in() && wc_customer_bought_product( '', get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id() ) ) {
      $is_purchasable = false;
   }
   return $is_purchasable;
}
```

Code sourced from https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-one-product-purchase/

In addition, I hope to add a button while hiding the Add to Cart button and download the current product directly, but I can't directly download the content directly on a single product page, I can only jump to the /my-account/downloads/ page through the URL . Therefore I used the following code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_message_if_not_purchasable', 29 );
 
function bbloomer_message_if_not_purchasable() {
   global $product;
   if ( is_user_logged_in() && wc_customer_bought_product( '', get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id() ) ) {
      echo '<a class="button  button_full_width button_download_single" href="https://youwebsite.com/my-account/downloads/"><span class="button_downloads">Go To download</span></a>';
   }
}
```

The main question should be on the URL, can you directly get the historical order number of the current product purchased by the user in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the order number on the product page but you have to find it first. I created this function that does exactly that:

```
function get_order_ids_for_product( $product_id, $customer_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $query = "
    SELECT o.ID
    FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS o
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS om ON o.ID = om.post_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS oi ON o.ID = oi.order_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS oim ON oi.order_item_id = oim.order_item_id
    WHERE o.post_type = 'shop_order'
    AND o.post_status IN ( 'wc-processing', 'wc-completed' )
    AND om.meta_key = '_customer_user'
    AND om.meta_value = %d
    AND oim.meta_key = '_product_id'
    AND oim.meta_value = %d
  ";

    $order_ids = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( $query, $customer_id, $product_id ) );

    return $order_ids;
}
```

The function will return `order_ids` of the orders that have the `product_id` and `customer_id` and are in **processing** or **completed** status. You can change and tweak this to match your needs.

Then you use that function to generate the url of the button that replaces the add to cart button.

```
function bbloomer_message_if_not_purchasable() {
    global $product;
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && wc_customer_bought_product('', get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id() ) ) {
        $matching_orders = get_order_ids_for_product($product->get_id(), get_current_user_id());
        if(count($matching_orders) > 0){
            echo '<a class="button  button_full_width button_download_single" href="/my-account/view-order/'.$matching_orders[0]->ID.'/"><span class="button_downloads">Go To download</span></a>';
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I am using only first order id because you said the user will buy the product only once. If for whatever reason, a customer has more than one orders with that product, this code will only link to one of them.